# Insert Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart") To Dynamic String?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have dynamic strings, for example

`hello bold italic {0} xxx {0}yyy {0} etc...`,

`abcd {0} how to xyz {0} newline {0}..etc...`,

and more.

How to insert `<% Html.RenderAction("CartSummary", "ShoppingCart"); %>` to the dynamic string at the `{0}` position?

Comment: can you please be little more clear...or else post little code snippet

Answer (score 0):

[`Html.RenderAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction.aspx) writes directly to the response. You could use [`Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.action.aspx) which returns an [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring.aspx).